# ASP.NET Core ViewComponent for asynchronous view rendering

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am developing a single page application in ASP.NET MVC. The ASP.NET Framework version is 4.5 and the MVC version is 4. I am wondering if ViewComponents in ASP.NET Core might help me with my problem.

### The Problem

The application has a single "proper" Index view and multiple child/nested partial views inside it that depend on some parent views' data, for example:

```
Index > GridPartial --> RowInfoPartial > AdditionalRowInfoPartial
```

where `>` denotes nesting, i.e. `GridPartial` is nested inside `Index` and `AdditionalRowInfoPartial` is nested inside `RowInfoPartial`; and `-->` denotes dependency injection, i.e. both `RowInfoPartial` and `AdditionalIRowInfoPartial` depend on some data from `GridPartial`.

Ideally, I would like to only show what I need to show, but unfortunately, it is not the case right now. All the nested partial views are rendered synchronously when the application is loaded, meaning loading the application is extremely slow. Moreover, because of dependencies, many partial views have to call their corresponding actions in the controller to pass their dependencies to business logic and show the correct data on the client, which slows the loading time even further.

### The Solution (?)

I've read up on ViewComponents in ASP.NET Core, and they seem to satisfy all my needs:

- They can be invoked asynchronously, to reduce loading time and only show views when needed
- Supports controller dependency injection
- Supports business logic

I want to make sure that ViewComponents do indeed help me solve my problem before I migrate to ASP.NET Core. Is my understanding of this technology correct, or is there some other way of solving my problem without having to migrate to ASP.NET Core?